# Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Database having version 6.0.0.809 is not supported for upgraded

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Getting following error when migrating from CRM 2011 Rollup update 14 to CRM 2013 sp1.
" Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Database having version 6.0.0.809 is not supported for upgraded."

Before installing SP1 on CRM 2013 the database CRM was importing with out any issue.The only change is SP1 installation and the database I am importing is actually another copy of same organization of CRM2011.

Anyone knows what's causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is misleading as it has nothing to do with the version of the database. If you are trying to import an organization database that has already been imported to an organization on that crm server, you will get this error, because the organization has the same ID.

Deleting the other org will do it. If you need both orgs, you can delete the previously imported one and reimport the already upgraded organization. This will assign it a new organization ID. Then you can proceed with upgrading the second copy.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to georged answer:
The solution for me was to Delete the old org, then **first** upgrade the second copy and only after the upgrade re-import the old one. The other way round didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If georged's solution doesn't work for you then try Tim's. I was going to post this as a comment, but it's too long for a comment.

I'm using a later version of CRM (CRM 9.0.4.5) but otherwise had the same problem. The only difference being that I was importing an organization that needed upgrading - the existing organization was a copy that I had previously upgraded.

From my understanding when you import an organisation, Deployment Manager is supposed to assign a new Organization ID if it detects a clash. Whilst that does seem to be how deployment manager works, that check seems to be bypassed if it also needs to upgrade the solution. (Perhaps a later version of Deployment Manager will fix that.)

So, using Deployment Manager:

1. delete the existing organization. The database will be preserved so it can be re-imported later.
2. import the new organization, it should now successfully import because there shouldn't be a clash.
3. re-import the original organiation that you just dropped.